# Python, detect letters with “in”

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, membership

I’m learning python and got stuck on the “in” keyword.
I want to write a simple code which detects the Turkish letters, for example ı,ş,ö,ç,ğ,ü. But my code never find those letters. It always prints `ok`. What can I do?

```py
usern = input("username:")
if usern in ("ş", "ı", "ö", "ç", "ü", "ğ"):
    print("turkish letter detected")
else:
    print("ok.")
```

Comment: You must iterate over each letter in "usern".

Answer (score 3):

The membership test is the other way around, and using `any()` will simplify things. Also, if you want a bit more extra efficiency, you can convert `usern` into a `set` object, for faster membership testing:

```
userset = set(usern)
if any(c in userset for c in ("ş","ı","ö","ç","ü","ğ")):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
usern=input(“username:”)
if any([let in [“ş”,“ı”,”ö”,”ç”,”ü”,”ğ”] for let in usern]):
     print(“turkish letter detected”)
else
    print(“ok.”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usern = input("username:")
chars_list = ["ş", "ı", "ö", "ç", "ü", "ğ"]
print ", ".join([letter for letter in list(usern) if letter in chars_list]])
```

1. With ***list(usern)*** you convert string to list
2. Then you check each letter if it's in the defined list of accepted letters.
3. At the end you print out the found letters.
4. Better to assign the list/tuple of valid characters in another variable so as to be ale to adjust/handle it easily when needed.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez used because I have the ability to print how many times a specific letter was in the input if I need so.

Comment: Yeah but you're not doing that in your answer. For the sake of argument: try removing the `list()` from your code - it'll work exactly as before!

Answer (score 0):

The most time efficient solution would probably be using hash maps.:

```py
from collections import Counter


def has_turkish_letter(word):
    turkish_letters = ["ş", "ı", "ö", "ç", "ü", "ğ"]
    letter_count = Counter(word.lower())
    for letter in turkish_letters:
        if letter_count.get(letter, 0) > 0:
            return True
    return False

if has_turkish_letter(usern):
    print("turkish letter detected")
else:
    print("ok.")
```